# Sorting date in mongodb using mm-dd-yyyy format

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

**Here is my sample document:**

> ```
> _id:5c10fd9def1d420ef80007af,
> date_claimed:"01-14-2018"
> ```

I'm trying to sort my `date_claimed` in ascending order, it is working properly using 2018 as end year but after I put some 2019 value, it doesn't follow the order. How can I fix this? I should follow the `mm-dd-yyyy` format

**Code:**

```
Bloodrequest.aggregate([{$group: {_id : "$date_claimed" , count:{$sum:1}}},{$sort: {_id: 1}}]
console.log(date2);
```

**Yields:**

```
[ { _id: '01-01-2019', count: 1 }, //this should be the most bottom
  { _id: '01-14-2018', count: 1 },
  { _id: '01-20-2018', count: 1 },
  { _id: '02-13-2018', count: 2 },
  { _id: '03-13-2018', count: 3 },
  { _id: '04-25-2018', count: 1 }]
```

Comment: `%Y%m%d` format will fix this issue. Or you can `$dateFromString` and order documents

Answer (score 2):

Since `mm-dd-yyyy` is not naturally sortable, any solution based on this field content would require a full collection scan and/or full collection manipulation to be able to do this, since you're essentially requiring a custom sort method on a string field.

This will be a major performance killer, and not practical to do in the long term.

I would suggest you store your `date_claimed` field into a proper `ISODate()` format, put an index on it for sorting purposes, and do `$project` (or similar method) into the required `mm-dd-yyyy` format for output purposes.

For example, if your document is structured like:

```
> db.test.find()
{
  "_id": 0,
  "date_claimed": ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00Z")
}
{
  "_id": 1,
  "date_claimed": ISODate("2018-01-02T00:00:00Z")
}
{
  "_id": 2,
  "date_claimed": ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00Z")
}
```

You can then create an index on the `date_claimed` field:

```
> db.test.createIndex({date_claimed:1})
```

You can display the sorted date in descending order as expected:

```
> db.test.aggregate([ {$sort: {date_claimed: -1}} ])
{ "_id": 2, "date_claimed": ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id": 1, "date_claimed": ISODate("2018-01-02T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id": 0, "date_claimed": ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
```

You can also use `$project` to display the date in `mm-dd-yyyy` format as required. Note that the documents are sorted properly:

```
> db.test.aggregate([ 
    {$sort: {date_claimed: -1}}, 
    {$project: {date_string: {$dateToString: {format: '%m-%d-%Y', date:'$date_claimed'}}}} 
])
{ "_id": 2, "date_string": "01-01-2019" }
{ "_id": 1, "date_string": "01-02-2018" }
{ "_id": 0, "date_string": "01-01-2018" }
```

See the [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) and the [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) manual page for more information.

There are a couple of good things from this method:

1. You can put an index on the date field, removing the necessity to perform ad-hoc manipulation on the whole collection.
2. By using the `ISODate()` field type, the whole [Date Expression Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-expression-operators) is now available for your use.

Answer (score 0):

Using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) converting the date into miliseconds and sorting using .sort()
would be your best bet I think. Something like this perhaps:

```
date2.map(res => {
let timeInMs = moment(res._id).unix() //gives you time in seconds
/* */
}).sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below:

```
Bloodrequest.aggregate([
              {
                   $group: {
                         _id :{
                                "day": { "$dayOfMonth" : "$date_claimed" },
                                "month": { "$month" : "$date_claimed" },
                                "year": { "$year" : "$date_claimed"}
                         } , 
                         count:{$sum:1}
                   }
              },
              {
                   $sort: {
                      "_id.year": 1,
                      "_id.month": 1,
                      "_id.day": 1 
                   }
              }
          ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Kevin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54193585/5800527) is the ideal solution. But if you're stuck not being able to change the schema for any reason, then you can use this solution:

```
Bloodrequest.dates.aggregate([
  {
    $group: { _id: "$date_claimed", count: { $sum: 1 } }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      date: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$_id",
          format: "%m-%d-%Y"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort:
      { date: 1 }
  }
])
```

As highlighted by Kevin, this is a performance killer. Should be used only when the data size is small and/or the frequency of this query being used is very low.